# Minecraft 1.14 How to summon a chest with nbt tag items inside

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

We are trying to `/setblock` a chest with a command block that has an item in slot 13 with the following properties.

- Name: 5 point PolyCoin
- NBT: An Official PolyCoin
- Has to have an enchanted glow to it.

The chest should appear at 9 2 8 in the world.

We have tried dozens of things from online, here are two of them:

```
/setblock 9 2 8 chest{Items:[{id:gray_dye,Damage:8,Slot:13,Count:1,display:{Name:5 Point PolyCoin,Lore:[Official PolyCraft Coins] } } ]}
/setblock 9 2 8 chest{Items:[{Slot:13,id:gray_dye,Count:1,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:fortune,lvl:3}]}}]} replace
```

Both only place a chest with a piece of gray dye inside.

Comment: @Dragonrage, Do you still think that the question in it´s current state is too broad? If so, then why do you think that? It was a very specific question, where the only thing I was unsure about was what the asker means with `NBT: An Official PolyCoin`.

Comment: @Mr.Bear, no, it looks fine now. I hadnt had a chance to check it again since i made my last comment, otherwise i probably wouldve retracted my vote. voting to reopen

Comment: @Dragonrage do the others get notified when you vote to reopen?

Comment: @Mr.Bear, no but it gets sent to the reopen queue

Answer (score 6):

You can get a `/setblock` command with <kbd>F3</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

To do so, you place a chest at `9 2 8` (This works for any block at any coordinates).

Then you fill the chest with the items that you want inside of it:

[image: A picture of the GUI of a chest containing a custom item]

You can get gray dye like the one from the image with this command:

```
/give @s minecraft:gray_dye{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:fortune",lvl:3s}],display:{Name:'{"text":"5 Point PolyCoin"}',Lore:['{"text":"An Official PolyCoin"}']}}
```

When you are done, you look at it and press <kbd>F3</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, there should be a message in chat:

[image: A screenshot from minecraft in first person view, looking at a chest and with a message in chat]

You can now paste your command into a command block, or a text editor by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (in windows):

```
/setblock 9 2 8 minecraft:chest[facing=north,type=single,waterlogged=false]{Items:[{Slot:13b,id:"minecraft:gray_dye",Count:1b,tag:{Enchantments:[{lvl:3s,id:"minecraft:fortune"}],display:{Lore:['{"text":"An Official PolyCoin"}'],Name:'{"text":"5 Point PolyCoin"}'}}}]}
```

You can edit the command, to make it a little shorter, by removing tags that you don't need, if you care about that (This may be more useful with different blocks):

```
/setblock 9 2 8 minecraft:chest{Items:[{Slot:13b,id:"minecraft:gray_dye",Count:1b,tag:{Enchantments:[{lvl:3s,id:"minecraft:fortune"}],display:{Lore:['{"text":"An Official PolyCoin"}'],Name:'{"text":"5 Point PolyCoin"}'}}}]}
```

Once you are done you can break the block that you made and use the command to set your custom block at that position. (This works for entities, too, simply look at the entity to get a `/summon` command with <kbd>F3</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>)

Comment: You can get a list of debug tools by pressing `F3+Q`, they include things like visible chunk borders (`F3+G`), visible hitboxes (`F3+B`), advanced tooltips (`F3+H`), and crashing the game (Press and hold `F3+C`). I used advanced tooltips when I made the screenshot off the contents of the chest with the gray dye.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [MCStacker for 1.13](https://mcstacker.net/1.13.php), it's a very good way to create commands, including `setblock`, with which you are able to place a chest, filled with custom items.
Another helpful page is [Minecraftjson.com](https://minecraftjson.com/), as it allows you to create `tellraw` commands, books, and other json-texts.

Comment: The second part of your answer is a comment: please post it as such: And please add links to websites you mention.